# .exe file (jarsigner) hangs when I try to start it through windows process (C++)

Tags: java, c++, process, jarsigner, waitforsingleobject

I have a simple jarsigner .apk file verification command:

```
jarsigner.exe -verify <path to .apk>
```

It works fine when I run it via windows cmd line.

I usually run .exe files in my application through special class, and this class works fine for some (a lot of, to be honest) .exe calls. (I get output of .exe files via pipes and wait for it through WaitForSingleObject function) I start process and wait for it, up to 60 seconds, for example.

But, for jarsigner.exe calls, I got very strange behaviour:

-When I start some simple commands, like just 'jarsigner.exe', it works fine (1-3 seconds and i got some output via pipes)

-When I start verification command ('jarsigner.exe -verify path-to-apk-file'), I can wait forever and still get no output (tried INFINITE timeout and waited a lot). If I run same command via windows cmd, it works (near 10-20 seconds).

Can somebody explain, please, is there any special cases of using jarsigner / windows processes mechanics, that may result in such strange behaviour?

Comment: Maybe the working directory is different when launching from the exe? Try giving it a non-existent path to apk in command line to see if it hangs.

Comment: If I give it non-existent path, it works: process successfully finishes and jarsigner displays an error message about non-existent path. The problem appears only when jarsigner really starts to validate the file.